# Можно ли как то оптимизировать запрос к бд в данном случае Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста можно ли как то оптимизировать данный запрос к бд в Laravel?

есть такой контроллер

```
public function notPublished()
{
       $adverts = $this->advertRepository->getForUser(Auth::user()->id);

       return view('profile.adverts.not_published.index', compact('adverts'));
}
```

метод из репозитория

```
public function getForUser(int $userId): LengthAwarePaginator
{
    return Advert::where('user_id', $userId)->orderByDesc('id')->paginate(20);
}
```

который возвращает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

связи в модели Advert

```
public function region()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Region::class, 'region_id', 'id');
}

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id', 'id');
}
```

в виде есть такой foreach который разбирает адверты

```
@foreach ($adverts as $advert)
                @if ($advert->isNotPublished())
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $advert->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $advert->updated_at }}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{ route('adverts.show', $advert) }}" target="_blank">{{ $advert->title }}</a></td>
                    <td>
                        @if ($advert->region)
                            {{ $advert->region->name }}
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ $advert->category->name }}</td>
                </tr>
                @endif
@endforeach
```

вот что показывает debug панель

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
select * from `users` where `id` = 2 limit 1
8.9ms
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php:52
app
select count(*) as aggregate from `advert_adverts` where `user_id` = 2
400μs
/app/Domain/Ads/Advert/Repository/AdvertRepository.php:12
app
select * from `advert_adverts` where `user_id` = 2 order by `id` desc limit 20 offset 0
520μs
/app/Domain/Ads/Advert/Repository/AdvertRepository.php:12
app
select * from `regions` where `regions`.`id` = 4400 limit 1
540μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:39
app
select * from `advert_categories` where `advert_categories`.`id` = 373 limit 1
420μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:44
app
select * from `regions` where `regions`.`id` = 4400 limit 1
410μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:39
app
select * from `advert_categories` where `advert_categories`.`id` = 393 limit 1
260μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:44
app
select * from `regions` where `regions`.`id` = 4400 limit 1
290μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:39
app
select * from `advert_categories` where `advert_categories`.`id` = 376 limit 1
230μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:44
app
select * from `regions` where `regions`.`id` = 4400 limit 1
200μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:39
app
select * from `advert_categories` where `advert_categories`.`id` = 375 limit 1
300μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:44
app
select * from `regions` where `regions`.`id` = 4400 limit 1
210μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:39
app
select * from `advert_categories` where `advert_categories`.`id` = 372 limit 1
200μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:44
app
select * from `regions` where `regions`.`id` = 4400 limit 1
230μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:39
app
select * from `advert_categories` where `advert_categories`.`id` = 372 limit 1
190μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:44
app
select * from `regions` where `regions`.`id` = 4400 limit 1
210μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:39
app
select * from `advert_categories` where `advert_categories`.`id` = 372 limit 1
240μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:44
app
select * from `regions` where `regions`.`id` = 4400 limit 1
180μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:39
app
select * from `advert_categories` where `advert_categories`.`id` = 372 limit 1
200μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:44
app
select * from `regions` where `regions`.`id` = 4400 limit 1
300μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:39
app
select * from `advert_categories` where `advert_categories`.`id` = 389 limit 1
230μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:44
app
select * from `regions` where `regions`.`id` = 4400 limit 1
260μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:39
app
select * from `advert_categories` where `advert_categories`.`id` = 372 limit 1
250μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:44
app
select * from `regions` where `regions`.`id` = 4400 limit 1
250μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:39
app
select * from `advert_categories` where `advert_categories`.`id` = 372 limit 1
230μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:44
app
select * from `regions` where `regions`.`id` = 4400 limit 1
220μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:39
app
select * from `advert_categories` where `advert_categories`.`id` = 372 limit 1
150μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:44
app
select * from `regions` where `regions`.`id` = 4400 limit 1
240μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:39
app
select * from `advert_categories` where `advert_categories`.`id` = 372 limit 1
250μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:44
app
select * from `regions` where `regions`.`id` = 4400 limit 1
250μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:39
app
select * from `advert_categories` where `advert_categories`.`id` = 372 limit 1
220μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:44
app
select * from `regions` where `regions`.`id` = 4400 limit 1
170μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:39
app
select * from `advert_categories` where `advert_categories`.`id` = 372 limit 1
200μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:44
app
select * from `regions` where `regions`.`id` = 4400 limit 1
310μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:39
app
select * from `advert_categories` where `advert_categories`.`id` = 372 limit 1
260μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:44
app
select * from `regions` where `regions`.`id` = 4400 limit 1
300μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:39
app
select * from `advert_categories` where `advert_categories`.`id` = 372 limit 1
230μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:44
app
select * from `regions` where `regions`.`id` = 4400 limit 1
220μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:39
app
select * from `advert_categories` where `advert_categories`.`id` = 372 limit 1
220μs
view::profile.adverts.not_published.index:44
app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете сделать загрузку нужных category и region для Advert, используя [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads):

```
public function getForUser(int $userId): LengthAwarePaginator
{
    return Advert::with(['region', 'category'])->where('user_id', $userId)->orderByDesc('id')->paginate(20);
}
```

Либо если эти данные нужны будут всегда, то в классе Advert:

```
public class Advert extends Model
{
    // ...

    /**
     * The relations to eager load on every query.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = ['region', 'category'];

    // ...
}
```